# Windbg loads symbols from an altered location

Tags: c++, windbg, symbols, debug-symbols

Using the symbols window(CTRL + S), i have set WinDbg to load my symbols from a specific location.

[image]

Now when i attach my debugger and try to view the stack window, it seems like symbols aren't really loaded properly.

[image]

Now, when i use the *!sym noisy* command and *.reload /f*, i get the following info from the debugger:

[image]

So, from the third picture, why is SYMSRV is even defined? and why is it adding the GUID prefix to the end of the file?

It would've worked if it wasn't that guid windbg adds to the path. What am i doing wrong.

**EDIT**: after reviewing the log furthermore, i see that the debugger attemps to load the symbol from the local drive.

[image]

Comment: Windbg has some default search paths preset it will always look for symbols in those path if it  cant find symbols in the preferred path what is the problem

Comment: @blabb, As mentioned, i have defined symbol's path and verified that access is plausible via network. but according the logs, windbg appends GUID to file's name (i believe it tries to download it using windows' symbols server)

Comment: What's the output of `.sympath`?

Comment: The format of directory to symbol path is basedirr/modname/guid/actualsymbolfile. Ieit can be x:/foo/myspecsym/blah.pdb/123456vvvvxxxx/blah.pdb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several different formats in which symbols can be stored. These are 0-tier, 2-tier and 3-tier.

0-tier is basically a flat list of files, which is suitable if you have just built your program and all the PDBs are located in one folder. If you enter a local path like `c:\path` or server share like `\\server`, WinDbg should consider a 0-tier store layout, but might try others as well.

The problem is that you can only store one version of PDBs in a 0-tier store, which is why the 2-tier and 3-tier symbol stores exist. When symbols are added to such a store, it will consider the GUID, so it is possible to store several versions of the same program. 2- and 3-tier symbol stores should start with `srv*`. The exact difference between a 2-tier and a 3-tier store is explained in Channel 9 [episode 87](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-87-Symbol-Folder-Hierarchy-index2-txt) and it's possible to [convert](http://debugging.wellisolutions.de/convertstore-errors/) a 2-tier store into a 3-tier store.

Do not confuse the `srv*` symbol path syntax with the `SYMSRV:` debug output. IMHO the `SYMSRV:` is just a debug message of the `symsrv.dll`, so nothing to worry about.

The truth about loading symbols can only be monitored with [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx). Not all location where WinDbg searches for symbols are logged, even in the noisy mode.

In addition to the symbol path, DLLs contain a reference to the local path of the PDB and WinDbg will consider this path, independent of the symbol path settings.

Comment: Perhaps (I never tried) you can disable loading from the DLL path by setting `.symopt+ 0x80` (SYMOPT_IGNORE_CVREC)